# react - how to add DOMAttribute to custom component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom React component in typescript:

```
const MyButton: React.FC = ({children, ...props}) => {
  return (<button {...props}>{children}</button>)
}
```

When I try to use this component, adding a DOMAttribute (e.g. onClick):

```
<MyButton onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}></MyButton>
```

I get this error:

```
Type '{ onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

How can I modify MyButton so that it accepts DOMAttributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`, like so:

```
const MyButton: React.FC<HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>> = ({children, ...props}) => {
   return (<button {...props}>{children}</button>) 
}
```

If you want to add own custom props as well extend the props interface, like this:

```
interface IMyButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  customProp: string;
}

const MyButton: React.FC<IMyButtonProps> = props => {
   const {children, customProp, ...rest} = props;

   return <button {...rest}>{children}</button> 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I get a different error with this setup (very long error message , this is what I think the key): Type '{ children: ReactNode; accept?: string | undefined; acceptCharset?: string | undefined; action?: string | undefined; allowFullScreen?: boolean | undefined; allowTransparency?: boolean | undefined; ... 353 more ...; key?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited my post it should work now. Use `HTMLAttributes` instead of `HTMLProps`. It's weird, sometimes that one works, sometimes the other.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer with info about custom props, that would've been my next question :)